# How to calculate fuel burn rate in Model BK117 helicopter

Tags: helicopter, flight-dynamics, fuel-consumption

I am confused which parameters we are use, I have fuel quantity, fuel flow, fuel weight and speed etc is there so how to using and which parameters using the Endurance time calculate in helicopter

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why you would need to calculate these for that specific helicopter. You can get these values much more accurately from a Google search

Comment: @AadirajAnil these questions are normally related to some homework problem...

Answer (score 1):

Given the fuel quantity and the fuel flow, it should be quite trivial to calculate endurance. Consider the following:

Fuel flow simply states the amount of fuel consumed during a given timespan. For example: $\dot{f} = 5 \frac{l}{min}$. Together with a given fuel quantity e.g. $f_{total} = 697 l$ we can now calculate the time until this fuel quantity is consumed:

$t_{endurance} = \frac{f_{total}}{\dot{f}} = \frac{697 l}{5 \frac{l}{min}} = 139 min$

It should be noted that these are approximate values, I do not claim that these values represent the actual aircraft examples exactly.